# how to pass data in Zeppelin to DS3.js for Spark visualization

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

The graph options with Zeppelin are pretty basic.  So I am looking for an example of how to do something simple, like a barchart, with ds3.js.  From what I can tell that would be the best graphing library to use to create stunning graphs.

Anyway my question is how to pass data to the JavaScript code.  With regular Zeppelin charts you write scala or other code and then save that in a dataframe.  Then on the next line you use the %sql option and you can write a SQL command and then buttons appear to let you graph the data.

But what I have found looking on the internet is no indication that data created in the scala code section would be passed to the Angular section where you put the ds3.js code.

Some examples I found are like this one where all the html and Javascript is put in one giant print statement in the scala code https://rawkintrevo.org/2016/09/20/gelly-on-apache-flink/

And then there is an example like this one [Using d3.js with Apache Zeppelin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414482/using-d3-js-with-apache-zeppelin) where the Zeppelin line is all JavaScript, but the data is just a locally created array.

So I need (1) an example and (2) some understanding of how RDDs ad Dataframes can be passed into the JavaScript code, which of course is on a different line that the scala code.  How do you bring objects in the scala section of the notebook into scope for the Javascript section.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [zeppelin docs](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/development/writingzeppelinvisualization.html) for a good getting-started guide to creating custom visualization. Also, you might want to check out [the code of some of the built-ins viz](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/tree/master/zeppelin-web/src/app/visualization/builtins).

Regarding how data from DataFrames are passed to js, I'm pretty sure `z.show` or `%sql` triggers `dataFrame.take(${zeppelin.spark.maxResult})` which *collects* the `RDD[T]` as a `Seq[T]` object to the driver whose elements are then used to render graphs.

Alternatively if you have a javascript graph defined in another paragraph, you can also use`z.angularBind("values", rdd.take(maxResult))` to send the data to the angular view. There's a really nice answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335170/how-to-put-a-variable-into-z-zeppelincontext-in-javascript-in-zeppelin) on the subject which might help.

Hope you find this helpful.